# javascript count nested property

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that has some predefined properties, like so:

```
var dataObj = {
    noun: {
        definitions: [],
        ...
    },
    verb: {
        definitions: [],
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

my code populates this object based on the word provided, and in the end, the object might look something like this:

```
var dataObj = {
    noun: {
        definitions: ['something']
    },
    verb: {
        definitions: ['something else']
    },
    adjective: {
        definition: []
    }
};
```

My question is how can I count how many properties actually have definitions in the definitions array property?

Comment: Use a loop, and add to a counter when `dataObj[key].definitions.length > 1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. [Get the values within your object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
2. [Filter that collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to non-empty `definitions`
3. Count the items

```js
var dataObj = {
    noun: {
        definitions: ['something']
    },
    verb: {
        definitions: ['something else']
    },
    adjective: {
        definition: [] // definition?
    }
};

const count = Object.values(dataObj)
  .filter(({ definitions }) => definitions?.length > 0)
  .length
  
console.log("Found", count)
```

Answer (score -1):

not sure how deep it goes but if it can be several layers deep you can do it recursively.

```js
var dataObj = {
  noun: {
    definitions: ['something']
  },
  verb: {
    definitions: ['something else']
  },
  adjective: {
    definition: []
  },
  test: {
    test2: {
      definitions: ['something else']
    }
  }
};



let counter = 0;
console.log(`found: ${iterate(dataObj)}`);

function iterate(obj) {
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (property === 'definitions' && obj[property].length) {
      counter++;
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
        iterate(obj[property]);
      }

    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```